# How to repositioning google rechapta popup?

Tags: css

Im trying to fix Google Rechapta popup Position, and im already trying to modify .grecaptcha-badge class.

how can i fix this?
[GoogleRechapta Positioning](https://i.stack.imgur.com/R8nN0.png)

Answer (score 0):

you  may inject css to the id element

```
#your_ID{

  margin-left: 10px;   
  width: 100px;

}
```